# ¿Cómo actualizar valores de un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python, revisión-de-código, diccionarios

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente diccionario en Python:

```
 letters= {0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c',
 3: 'd',
 4: 'e',
 5: 'f',
 6: 'g',
 7: 'h',
 8: 'i',
 9: 'j',
 10: 'k',
 11: 'l',
 12: 'm',
 13: 'n',
 14: 'o',
 15: 'p',
 16: 'q',
 17: 'r',
 18: 's',
 19: 't',
 20: 'u',
 21: 'v',
 22: 'w',
 23: 'x',
 24: 'y',
 25: 'z',
 26: ' '}
```

Y que cambio de orden las llaves y los valores con la siguiente dict comprehension:

```
encoding = {y:x for x,y in letters.items()}
```

Lo siguiente que quiero hacer es que, para cada letra (key), se aumente su valor en 3 utilizando lo siguiente:

```
ek= 3
```

De esa forma, tendríamos:

```
'a': 3
'b': 4
```

y así sucesivamente.

¿Cómo puedo lograr eso sin tener que hacerlo de forma manual? Quisiera poner alguna idea pero estas dos aproximaciones no tuvieron éxito:

```
encoding= {sum(ek) for x in encoding.values()}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable


encoding.update(sum(ek) in encoding.values())
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada.
¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo directamente en la creación de `encoding`, sumando la variable

```
ek = 3
encoding = {v: k+ek for k, v in letters.items()}
```

La función preconstruida `sum`  recibe un iterable y retorna la suma de sus items iterando sobre el. Tu le estas pasando los valores del diccionario, que son enteros, de ahí el error (no se puede iterar sobre un entero).

Si no quieres hacer la suma en la creación de `encodig` puedes usar un ciclo `for` para modificar los valores 'in-place' posteriormente:

```
for key in encoding:
    encoding[key] += ek
```

O usando `dict.update`:

```
encoding.update({k: v + ek for k, v in encoding.items()})
```

De cualquier forma, la salida es:

> ```
> {'a': 3,
>  'b': 4,
>  'c': 5,
>  'd': 6,
>  'e': 7,
>  'f': 8,
>  'g': 9,
>  'h': 10,
>  'i': 11,
>  'j': 12,
>  'k': 13,
>  'l': 14,
>  'm': 15,
>  'n': 16,
>  'o': 17,
>  'p': 18,
>  'q': 19,
>  'r': 20,
>  's': 21,
>  't': 22,
>  'u': 23,
>  'v': 24,
>  'w': 25,
>  'x': 26,
>  'y': 27,
>  'z': 28,
>  ' ': 29,}
> ```